# iOS UIWebView shows nothing but black background

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I use pushViewController to navigate to my webview (in a navigation based app), and I use NSLog in my webview to check the url. It turns out the url is passed successfully but the webview shows nothing except black background.

```
    WebViewController *webView = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
    [webView setUrl:finalURL];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webView animated:YES];
```

In WebViewController.m----viewWillAppear:

```
    NSLog(@"%@", _url); // I got the url!!!!!!!!!
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_url]];
```

Comment: how did you add web view to web view controller?

Comment: Try adding `NSLog(@"%@", self.view);` in viewWillAppear: and see what it shows.

Comment: Also **NSLog(@"%@", webView);**

Comment: @Kreiri  I'm using a web view in one of my storyboard UIView so it didn't work. Finally I make a new xib and put in a web view, it works.

Comment: @PhillipMills I'm using a web view in one of my storyboard UIView so it didn't work. Finally I make a new xib and put in a web view, it works.

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith I'm using a web view in one of my storyboard UIView so it didn't work. Finally I make a new xib and put in a web view, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you Connected web view outlet to the `webView` ? in `.xib` file

Comment: I'm using a web view in one of my storyboard UIView so it didn't work. Finally I make a new xib and put in a web view, it works.